# display: flex in ancessor and one of its child bring errors.

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Good day.

Second time in my large CSS project I found that if ancessor and it's child have a display: flex property. This leads to error. I cannot formulate what conditions for this bug. And this time I think I found one more of it's appearance:

1) On Desktop Chrome works fine: https://youtu.be/e6jIKx7KM7s
2) On Iphone dose not works: https://youtu.be/0Nw_dHPhYZQ

Usually this error happens on iPhone, but some times even desktop chrome fails in rendering. https://gist.github.com/lbvf50mobile/5dc976a3a451ac491159ea6b5d971482

First/second "display: flex": I have when set generate sticky footer with scrolling and holy grail layouts.

Third "display: flex" inside swiper-slider and this leads to error on Safary/Chrome of the iPhone 6s.

What do you think it is?

thank you

Comment: Error was fixed by changing: 
 & a.center{ flex: 1 100;} & .text{flex: 100 1}
to
 & a.center{ } & .text{flex: 1}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score -1):

Error was fixed by simplifying code:

Code with BUGS:

```
main.pose .center{   
  & a.center{flex: 1 100;} 
  & .text{flex: 100 1;}
}
```

Simplified BUG-FREE code:

```
main.pose .center{   
  & a.center{} 
  & .text{flex: 1;}
}
```